# Selected MenuItem not displayed when selected from Select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am dynamically populating my dropdown from the axios.get. When an option is selected, its not displaying in the select box.

```
    componentDidMount = (e) => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(res => {
            const FullData = res.data;
            this.setState({ FullData })
            console.log(FullData)
        })
        }
```

handleChange method-

```
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
}
```

render comp -

```
<FormControl fullWidth={true}>
   <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">*Select</InputLabel>
        <Select
         name="domains"
         labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
         id="demo-simple-select"
         placeholder="Select"
         onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            {FullData
              .filter(user => user.address.city === "Wisokyburgh")
              .map(user => {
               return <MenuItem key={user.id} id={user.id} value={user.zipcode}>
                                    {user.address.street}</MenuItem>
                                                            })}
             </Select>
       </FormControl>
```

What is the issue?

Comment: You probably forgot to specify a value for the <Select> component, only onChange handler

Comment: I didn't get it. Could you explain what value?

Comment: I mean something like ```<Select value={this.state.FullData.zipcode}>``` or whatever it should be. 
<Select
         name="domains"
         labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
         id="demo-simple-select"
         placeholder="Select"
         onChange={this.handleChange}
         **value={this.state.FullData.zipcode}**
          >

Answer (score 0):

To preserve selected value you need a state `selectedZipCode` and after `onChange` update it.

For MenuItem `value={user.zipcode}` zipcode is property of address so `value={user.address.zipcode}` as per [API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users)

see [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-select-with-class-e4dbr) for running code.

#### 1. Single Selection (with single Select Field):

```
class SelectComoponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      FullData: [],
      //COMMENT: added this new state to preserve selected zipcode
      selectedZipCode: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = (e) => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then((res) => {
      const FullData = res.data;
      this.setState({ FullData });
    });
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      //COMMENT: update only zip code
      selectedZipCode: event.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FormControl fullWidth={true}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">*Select</InputLabel>
        <Select
          //COMMENT: set selected value
          value={this.state.selectedZipCode || ""}
          name="domains"
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          placeholder="Select"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
          {this.state.FullData
            .filter(user => user.address.city === "Wisokyburgh")
            .map((user) => {
              return (
                <MenuItem
                  key={user.id}
                  id={user.id}
                  //COMMENT: as I see api response - zipcode is property of address object
                  value={user.address.zipcode}
                >
                  {user.address.street}
                </MenuItem>
              );
            })}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    );
  }
}

export default SelectComoponent;
```

#### 2. Multiple Selection (with single select fields): [my understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64113300/selected-menuitem-not-displayed-when-selected-from-select/64116875#comment113413127_64116875)

Note: I removed some code with ... is similar to code 1

```
 class SelectComoponent extends React.Component {
          constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
              ....
              // this is a array which has multiple selected values
              zipCodes: [] 
            };
          }
        
          handleChange = (event) => {

            this.setState({
              ...this.state,
              // here multiple values assigned to zipCodes
              zipCodes: event.target.value 
            });
          };
        
          render() {
            return (
            ...
                <Select
                  // this allow you to select multiple
                  multiple  
                  name="domains"
                  labelId="domains-select-label"
                  id="domains-select"
                >
```

#### 3. Multiple Selection (with multiple select fields): [maybe it answer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64113300/selected-menuitem-not-displayed-when-selected-from-select/64116875#comment113412066_64116875)

Note: I removed some code with ... is similar to code 1.

```
class SelectComoponent extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          ....
          // this is a object which has all select fields value
          zipCode: { domains: "", secondDomains: ""} 
        };
      }
    
      handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          zipCode: {
            ...this.zipCode,
            //this will match select name with state zipCode property name
            [event.target.name] = event.target.value 
          }
        });
      };
    
      render() {
        return (
        ...
            <Select
              value={this.zipCode.domains}
              //this name match with state zipCode properties
              name="domains"
              labelId="domains-select-label"
              id="domains-select"
            >
        ...
            <Select
              value={this.zipCode.secondDomains}
              name="secondDomains"
              labelId="secondDomains-select-label"
              id="secondDomains-select"
            >
        ...
```

Comment: I get the usege of value and the handleChange. If I now want to post this data to db, I can access the select value from {user.address.zipcode} right?

Comment: No, selected value is in state `this.state.selectedZipCode` so this value you can post to db.

Comment: [handling-multiple-inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs]) it may be useful for you to get all data from form element and on form submit you will post to api (database).

Comment: sure. Since its a single select text field you've used selectedZipCode right? What if there were multiple select fields? Will I have to declare new variables for every select?

Comment: If you talking about  [multiple-select](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#multiple-select) so you need `selectedZipCodes` array to store multiple selected values.

Comment: I updated answer I think you are talking about 3 point hope all the point will helpful for you.

Comment: yes, I meant multiple select fields (the 3rd option). I tried that code but it brings me to my first problem, the selected fields are not visible when selected.

Comment: [https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-select-with-class-e4dbr](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-select-with-class-e4dbr) updated code with option 3 have a look.

Comment: so I understand that with every new select field I'll need to add it under the initial state of zipcode right? Is there any other way this can be done? The solution you provided works btw!! thanks

Comment: Can you send the id and name in selecting a single option?
Ex: when I click on an option from dropdown can I send the street, zipcode and the city to the handleSelect?